# translate caption of default Haystack form template

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-haystack

i want to translate the caption "Search In :" in default Django-Haystack Search form to  frensh 'Chercher dans :' i don't find the form or the template.
thanks.

in search_indxess.py i add

```
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView
```

then in class class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable) i add

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
    self.fields['search_in'].label = "Chercher dans:"
```

but i have "global name 'SearchForm' is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

See the code of the Haystack forms here:
[Python Code of Haystack forms](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/forms.py)

Customize the code (so you can change the "search in" in "ModelSearchForm" in eny language you want) and import customized forms in your views, send them to your template and be happy.

Backup solution: displaying haystack form not as {{ form.as_p}} (or whatever) but separating fields as you like.

With {{ form.q}} you will get the search field, with {{ form.models }} you will get the list of defined models to search in. So you could also just use the later suggestion and put an

#### Chercher dans

right above the {{ form.models }} part ;-)